# Do i need to use an instance variable for this?

Tags: java, object

I am currently working on a Java coding exercise my lecturer gave. However, it is kind of confusing and i am confused as to how I am supposed to do it.

The part of the exercise looks like this:
Create an abstract class, Employee class, based on the following specifications:
- A private instance variable “name” (a string) for storing the name of an employee;
- A constructor that takes the name of the employee to be created;
- A public method, getName, that returns the name of the employee;
- A public method, getWorkingHoursPerWeek, that returns the number of working hours per week of the employee (an integer, default 40);
- A public method, getSalary, that returns the salary of the employee (an integer, default 11,000);
- A public method, getVacationDays, that returns the number of vacation days of the employee (an integer, default 10);
- An abstract public method, jobDuty, that returns the job duty of the employee (a string); and
- An abstract public method, jobTitle, that returns the job title of the employee (a string).

Am i supposed to make an instance variable for the working hours per week? How is it that there is a method to return a value for something that is not there?? Do i just return it as 40, and for later subclasses do i change the value?

```
public abstract class Employee {
    private String name;

    public Employee(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getWorkingHoursPerWeek(){
        return 40;
    }

    public abstract String jobDuty(String duty);

    public abstract String jobTitle(String title);
}
```

Comment: Just return 40. You are making an abstract class so your sub-classes will probably have a better implementation of this depending on what kind of employee type it is.

Comment: Well you were told to create an instance variable `name`, but you weren't told to create an instance variable `workingHoursPerWeek`. I don't know whether that also means it's *forbidden* to create an instance variable, you get to be the judge of that.

Comment: I think you are supposed to create an instance variable `workingHoursPerWeek` and initialize it directly or in the constructor with `40`... If it is forbidden to create an instance variable, then just `return 40;`, as you do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Inheritance

In Java, an Abstract class is one that should be instanced directly. Instead, a **child class** should be made, that inherits from it.

In this case, I would infer that there will be child classes of your `Employee` abstract class.

Child classes can **override** methods of their parents. And in the case of abstract methods, they *must* override them (unless the child class is also abstract).

Thus I think following the instructions as you have done with `getWorkingHoursPerWeek` is fine, and that child classes can override that method if they need to.

> Do i just return it as 40, and for later subclasses do i change the value?

I am assuming that **yes**, this is what is asked of you, based on the fact it's an abstract class, and the fact that they *have* specified to mention one instance variable, and have not mentioned that they would like others.

Comment: "I would infer", given that it is an abstract class I think you can do much more than infer ;)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: You're right, but I like to be clear with my assumptions and inferences so when I make mistakes it's easier to know which knowledge (based on the assumptions) to then discard or reconsider.

Answer (score 0):

> How is it that there is a method to return a value for something that is not there??
>   Blockquote

You could set the defaults to private variables (say, `private final String workingHoursPerWeek`), but this is not necessary as these values will only be used as a default return value.

> Do i just return it as 40, and for later subclasses do i change the value?

Yes, you can override methods in Java, so you will be able to add more logic and state to classes which inherit from `Employee`.